# keep getting an error 'function @ 0xb6ff9924 (or something similar)'

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, raw-input

I am attempting to create a little program that will calculate the area of a shape. When ever I put in the name of the shape it prints out "function at 0xetc". I am having a heck of a time figure out where the issue is. I know that my `area` function is probably messed up but I can't get there to debug it. I initial thought that I had defined functions with the same names as the shapes, it was calling them from the input but I change the names and I get the same message. here is the code:

```
#geometry program

#shapes

def squar(x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

def rectangl(x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

def circl(r):
    result = 3.14 * (r^2)
    return result

def triangl(h, b):
    result = (h^b * b)/2
    return result

s = raw_input("Shapes are square, rectangle, circle or triangle. Pick a shape and I will calculate its area. ")



#Calculating the area

def area(s):
   if str(s) == "square":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        squar(x, y)
        return squar
    elif str(s) == "rectangle":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        rectangl(x,y)
        return rectrangl
    elif str(s) == "circle":
        r = int(raw_input("Radius?" ))
        circl(r)
        return circl
    elif str(s) == "triangle":
        h = int(raw_input("Height?" ))
        b = int(raw_input("Base Width?" ))
        triangl(h, b)
        return triangl

    else:
        print "I don't know that one"


print area
```

thanks
ps. If the indenting looks a bit off by a space or two it is because of the formatting here. they aren't throwing up any error when I run the program.

Comment: You are returning _function itself_. Try returning _result of function call_ - e.g. `return rectangl(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in total 6 errors that you need to fix:

- In `area()` class, remove all the 4 return instructions you have.
- As the 4 methods you are calling in area() return values, you need to display their results by: `print method_name(arguments)`
- Finally, you will have to correctly instantiate the class `area()`

Here is how to fix the errors mentioned above:

```
# Shapes
def squar(x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

def rectangl(x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

def circl(r):
    result = 3.14 * (r^2)
    return result

def triangl(h, b):
    result = (h^b * b)/2
    return result

s = raw_input("Shapes are square, rectangle, circle or triangle. Pick a shape and I will calculate its area. ")

# Calculating the area
def area(s):
    if str(s) == "square":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        print squar(x, y)
    elif str(s) == "rectangle":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        print rectangl(x,y)
    elif str(s) == "circle":
        r = int(raw_input("Radius?" ))
        print circl(r)
    elif str(s) == "triangle":
        h = int(raw_input("Height?" ))
        b = int(raw_input("Base Width?" ))
        print triangl(h, b)
    else:
        print "I don't know that one"

area(s)
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

your main problem is simple, you don't call the functions.

In your last line `print area` what you get there is the position in memory where that function is located, you need to call it as `print area(s)` with your previously defined variable `s`.

Then in your function `area` you do the same, somehow it look like you think that the result of a function call is magically save in a variable of the same name as the function, but that is not the case, you need to do the same you do in yours *shape* functions, save the result in variable and return it, for example

```
result = squar(x,y)
return result
```

or better yet, return the result directly

```
return squar(x,y)
```

In python, everything is a object, functions included, so when you do `return squar` you are returning a function object.

A corrected version of your code may be:

```
#geometry program

#shapes

def rectangl(x, y):
    return  x * y

def circl(r):
    return 3.14 * (r**2)

def triangl(h, b):
    return (h^b * b)/2

#Calculating the area    

def area(s):
   if s == "square" or s == "rectangle":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        return rectangl(x, y)
    elif s == "circle":
        r = int(raw_input("Radius?" ))
        return circl(r)
    elif s == "triangle":
        h = int(raw_input("Height?" ))
        b = int(raw_input("Base Width?" ))
        return triangl(h, b)
    else:
        print "I don't know that one"

s = raw_input("Shapes are square, rectangle, circle or triangle. Pick a shape and I will calculate its area. ")
print area(s)
```

other thing with your code is that you don't need to call `str` in something that is already a string; also a square is a rectangle, you can use the same function for both; and exponentiation in python is done with `**` like `2**5`; there are other thing like instead of printing a message throwing a exception, but I leave that to your taste

Answer (score 0):

I think you get confused with function name and its return value, here is what learned from [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Functions/functions.html):

"In Python, a function is a named sequence of statements that belong together."
"The return statement is followed by an expression which is evaluated. Its result is returned to the caller as the “fruit” of calling this function."
Function itself is an object, its name is like a variable name, but its name indicates the entrance point of a piece of code. That is why when you call print statement to print the function name, it prints function ... @ ...., your real purpose is to print out its return value of last call. So here is what I think you can do:

```
def area(s):
   if str(s) == "square":
        x = int(raw_input("Height? "))        
        y = int(raw_input("Width?" ))
        squar_return_value = squar(x, y)
        return squar_return_value
                 .
                 .
                 .

print area(s)
```

The assignment at 'squar_return_value =' would create a variable name associates with an object returned by function call "squar(x,y)", then you can use squar_return_value like you use x, y.
I hope this will help you to understand the difference between a function name and its return value.